# SQL - An element with the same key '' already exists in the ExpandoObject

Tags: sql

I'm testing SQL queries on the database: http://www.dofactory.com/sql/sandbox

My query is...

```
select datepart(dd, orderdate), sum(totalamount)
from [order]
group by datepart(dd, orderdate)
order by datepart(dd, orderdate)
```

But I get the error

> Error: An element with the same key '' already exists in the ExpandoObject.

If I remove either the `select datapart(dd, orderdate)` or the `sum(totalamount)` portion the query runs fine.

Can someone explain what's going on?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure. It's a test DB located at the dofactory link that I posted. You should be able to test run the query for yourself by following the link

Comment: You don't give your columns names (`expression AS name`). As a result, you end up with two nameless properties in your object, which isn't allowed as object member names have to be unique. Mix in some naming love. (Note that this is *not* an SQL error -- SQL doesn't care if you name your columns. It's an error from the object-relational mapping layer, which uses an `ExpandoObject` to store the results.)

Comment: Thanks Jeroen! That was the issue. This came about because I was having problems with another query though, which still isn't working. I'll create a new post for that I guess

Comment: Link to new post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730419/ibm-informix-sql-syntax-error-basic-query-from-microsoft-bids-to-cisco-uccx-dat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is essentially a duplicate column name error because the columns are both aggregates and do not have names.

Try:

```
select datepart(dd, orderdate) AS a, sum(totalamount) AS b  
from [order]  
group by datepart(dd, orderdate)  
order by datepart(dd, orderdate)
```