# IBM Informix-SQL syntax error, basic query from Microsoft BIDS to Cisco UCCX database

Tags: sql, informix, bids

I'm running the below query against an IBM Informix database and getting an `ERROR 42000: A syntax error has occurred`. The FROM and WHERE clauses run fine in other queries, so I'm looking at the SELECT and GROUP BY portions. Any ideas what's wrong with the syntax?

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "informix".agentconnectiondetail.sessionid) AS calls_abandoned, 
DAY("informix".agentconnectiondetail.startdatetime) AS Expr2

FROM         "informix".agentconnectiondetail, "informix".contactqueuedetail, "informix".contactservicequeue

WHERE     "informix".agentconnectiondetail.sessionid = "informix".contactqueuedetail.sessionid AND 
                      "informix".contactqueuedetail.targetid = "informix".contactservicequeue.recordid AND "informix".contactqueuedetail.disposition = 1 AND 
                      "informix".agentconnectiondetail.startdatetime BETWEEN '2016-10-1 00:00:00' AND CURRENT

GROUP BY DAY("informix".agentconnectiondetail.startdatetime)
```

The goal btw is to find the total number of unique calls (calls_abandoned) that occur on each day of the month (1-31).

Answer (score 1):

Replace the

GROUP BY DAY("informix".agentconnectiondetail.startdatetime)

by

GROUP BY 2

Comment: Or `GROUP BY Expr2`, at least with 12.10 (it may not work in all older versions of Informix, but I think the afflicted versions are out of support now anyway).

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm 80% sure that I already tried that and it gave the same syntax error; I'll give it a shot in the morning though. I'll also have to check which version of informix we're on.

Comment: It looks like we're using Informix 11.70. Is there another way to reach my end goal without upgrading? or is that the only option